# Add dynamic dependent field

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm developing a bot with Formflow. I want to create a dynamic field based on the value of the previous field entered by the user. How can I achive this?
Here is my attempt so far:

```
public string Name { get; set; }

public string Age { get; set; }

public static IForm<MyForm> BuildForm()
{
    return new FormBuilder<LlegadaBusForm>()
        .Field(nameof(Name)
        .Field(new FieldReflector<MyForm>(nameof(Age))
            .SetType(null)
            .SetDefine(async (state, field) =>
            {
                var data = await GetData(state.Name);
                foreach (var o in data)
                {
                    field
                        .AddDescription(o, o)
                        .AddTerms(o, o);
                }

                return true;
            })
        .Build();
}
```

The code is not working because the dynamic field is created before "Name" gets a value...so it crashes calling the method "GetData".
Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you guys you show me the right way ;)

Comment: Excellent, glad it helped!. Consider upvoting!

Comment: I don't see the resemblance of the question in the claimed ones as duplicates. I have almost the same issue with similar structure (getting the values asynchronously from http request) although it doesn't crash but the bot refuses to prompt the user for the dynamic choice question and skips to the others and then to onCompletion. If anyone could provide a clear answer to this question that may be helpful.

Comment: I have resolved the issue with my code. I was using int as a type and when I made it nullable the .setType worked. apparently this function had an issue although it doesn't throw exceptions!.